# How to make F12 work in MSDEV for non MSDEV project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense, msdev

I am working on a legacy (20 years plus) code base and doing the development in MSDEV 2010.  The code is not built in MSDEV, it is done via a batch file using nmake.

I have created an empty windows project in MSDEV and pointed it at the relevant binaries.  This works, I can either attach to the exe when it is running or run it in debug from the start - breakpoints, stepping etc all work.

However, I cannot use F12 to lookup the definition of things.  When I press it I just get told it cannot find the definition.  I have tried adding the files in but that does not seem to help.

Anyone know how I can set this up?

Comment: IntelliSense doesn't know anything about your project, it doesn't have any idea what source code files are used.  You'll have to create a regular project.

Comment: When you say 'create a regular project' - how do I do that?  Is a Windows app not a regular project?

Comment: Why use Visual Studio 2010 at all then? Why not use some other IDE with "ad-hoc intellisense" features?

Comment: The company standard is to use MSDEV 2010 so I have to use it (I just work here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was far easier than I thought.  There is a separate option in 2010 to create a project from existing code.

I simply created the project and added the code from the root of my source tree.  Intellisense now works (as does Phat Studio).

I am now trying to figure out how to set the build system up within MSDEV!